# Definite integration $\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\csc^2(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I am unable to find the definite integral for the given function.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\csc^2(x)dx$$

I tried integrating by parts and approaching it like an indefinite integral. But I am convinced that the problem involves some methods of definite integrals.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The way to get help here is to [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. "Please help quickly" is not the way things work here. Do use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You will need to use parts - twice. And we have no obligation to help you quickly. Saying something like that really gives the impression of a low-quality question.

Comment: I get the result by MATHEMATICA which gives $\frac{1}{8}\left( {{\pi ^2}\ln 4 - 7\zeta \left( 3 \right)} \right)$ where ${\zeta \left(  \cdot  \right)}$ is Riemann zeta function.

Comment: I am really sorry for being rude. I had been working on the problem for 2 days and had got pretty desperate for the solution. Could you please show how it is done?

Comment: @Zeta I am only in high school and don't know about the Riemann Zeta function. Could you please explain what it is?

Comment: @Zeta. Repeat your calculation since what you gave does not seem to be correst.

Comment: Why did you tag *Taylor-expansion* ? Any reason for it ?

Comment: The answer is $\pi \ln(2)$, not what @Zeta wrote.  But since the antiderivative of $x^2 \csc^2(x)$ is not elementary, you're not likely to get a "high school" level solution by looking at antiderivatives.

Comment: @Zeta Interesting, I get $$-i \left(x^2+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i x}\right)\right)-x^2 \cot (x)+2 x \log \left(1-e^{2 i x}\right)$$
for the indefinite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the indefinite integral of $x^2\csc^2x$ is not elementary, its definite integration still is. First, integrate-by-parts

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\csc^2x\>dx=-\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2d(\cot x)dx
=2\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x \>dx$$
$$=2\int_0^{\pi/2}xd(\ln \sin x)=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln \sin x\> dx=-2J\tag 1$$

where

$$J=\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln \sin x dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\ln \sin x dx
=\int_0^{\pi/4}(\ln \sin x + \ln\cos x)dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(\frac12\sin2 x )dx
=-\frac\pi4 \ln2 + \frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin t dt = -\frac\pi4 \ln2 + \frac12J$$

Thus, $J=-\frac\pi2\ln2$. Substitute $J$ into (1) to get

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\csc^2x\>dx=\pi\ln2$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you  obtained the third step of (1)?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez - Note $(\ln \sin x)'= \frac{(\sin x)'}{\sin x} = \frac{\ cos x}{\sin x} = \cot x$

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged *"taylor-expansion"*, let us try to see what we can do with it.

Start with 
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^9\right)$$
$$\sin^2(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2 x^6}{45}-\frac{x^8}{315}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$
$$x^2 \csc ^2(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2 x^6}{45}-\frac{x^8}{315}+O\left(x^{10}\right)}$$ Now, long division
$$x^2 \csc ^2(x)=1+\frac{x ^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{15}+\frac{2 x^6}{189}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
Integrating termwise
$$\int x^2 \csc ^2(x)\,dx=x+\frac{x^3}{9}+\frac{x^5}{75}+\frac{2 x^7}{1323}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ Using the bounds, this would give
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}x^2 \csc ^2(x)\,dx\sim \frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{\pi ^3}{72}+\frac{\pi ^5}{2400}+\frac{\pi ^7}{84672} \approx 2.16462$$ while the exact solution is $\pi  \log (2)\approx 2.17759$.

Let us see what happens if we add more terms in the base expansion of the sine (say to $O\left(x^{2n+1}\right)$. The numerical values will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 2.00144 \\
 2 & 2.12895 \\
 3 & 2.16462 \\
 4 & 2.17420 \\
 5 & 2.17671 \\
 6 & 2.17736 \\
 7 & 2.17753 \\
 8 & 2.17757 \\
 9 & 2.17758 \\
 10 & 2.17759
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you use the approximation

$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ proposed more than $1400$ years ago by  Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician, you will have
$$ x^2 \csc ^2(x) \sim \frac{\left(5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x\right)^2}{256 (\pi -x)^2}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition, then
$$ x^2 \csc ^2(x) \sim \frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{5 \pi ^3}{32 (x-\pi )}+\frac{25 \pi ^4}{256 (x-\pi)^2}+\frac{5 \pi ^2}{32}$$
$$\int x^2 \csc ^2(x)\,dx \sim \frac{x^3}{48}+\frac{5 \pi ^2 x}{32}+\frac{25 \pi ^4}{256 (\pi -x)}+\frac{5}{32}
   \pi ^3 \log (\pi -x)-\frac{17 \pi ^3}{96}$$ Using the bounds
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}x^2 \csc ^2(x)\,dx\sim \frac{137-120 \log (2)}{768} \pi ^3 \approx 2.17296$$